# Lazy-load Angular NgModule when Clarity tab is activated

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'd like to lazy load an Angular `NgModule` in conjunction with the activation of a Clarity tab.  The content of the tab will contain a component of the lazy-loaded module, like this:

```
<clr-tabs>
  <clr-tab>
    <button clrTabLink id="link1">Tab 1</button>
    <clr-tab-content id="content1" *clrIfActive>
      <component-in-lazy-loaded-module></component-in-lazy-loaded-module>
    </clr-tab-content>
  </clr-tab>
</clr-tabs>
```

Is there an event I can tap into to lazy-load the module *before* the content is loaded when the tab is activated?  After reviewing the [Clarity docs](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/tabs#top), it's not entirely clear how this can be accomplished.

I'm open to using Angular `Router` in conjunction with Clarity tabs, as lazy-loading using the router is straightforward.  I found an example of someone using `<router-outlet>` inside of each tab [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971142/display-first-tab-as-default-when-page-loads), but it seems a little hokey, as you have the same router outlet in every `<clr-tab-content>`, and I'm not sure if there are any side-effects or performance impacts for this.

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is actually a limitation in Angular right now where lazy loading is tied to the router. The reason you have to put a router-outlet multiple times is that the content of a tab is destroyed (clrIfActive) and a new tab must have it included.

Comment: There actually are ways to load modules with code, but they are pretty ugly, and you have to know a lot about the Angular internals.  I'd sooner shy away from that and use the router.  Thanks for the feedback.